# What is returned after child.waitFor() execution?

Tags: java

```
    String command = "javac -cp .:../sqljdbc.jar SetHash.java";
   Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  try{
  c= child.waitFor();
  } catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Hi...
I would like to know which value will be assigned to "c" variable in the above structure if the command runs successfully. Also I would like to know if there will be any change in the value that will be assigned to "c" if the command does end up with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6296560 it will return 0 if the compilation was successful (with or without warnings) and 1 if it was not.

Answer (score 2):

In the shallow sense, the value assigned to `c` is the return value of the invoked process.  The `Process` class itself has no control over the semantics of this, as the invoked process can return whatever it wants.  The convention for processes is to return `0` when terminating successfully, and a non-zero value to indicate an error.

As [jmo points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425703/what-is-returned-after-child-waitfor-execution/3425749#3425749), the return values from `javac` are 0 if compilation succeeded, and 1 if not (personally, I would still test for zero and non-zero here for future-proofing).  Hence you can test for:

```
final boolean compilationSucceeded = c ==0;
```

(and as an aside, `c` is a misleading variable.  Partly because it's not immediately obvious what it means, in the sense that `i` works fine as a loop counter; and also because by convention variables called `c` are characters, but here it's an `int`).